# Buying a variable inductor

Tags: rf, analog, inductor, radio, ham-radio

I need a variable inductor of about 70 nH. I found one at [Mouser](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Coilcraft/165-07A06SL?qs=ZYnrCdKdyee6%252Bz7Kfv5Qtg%3D%3D). [image]

As you can see, it says that its inductance is 70 nH, but when I open the [datasheet](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/597/uni5-463500.pdf) it says that inductance is from 9 to over 280 nH. What does that 70 nH I've choosen actually mean then? How much will my inductor vary, from 9 to 280 nH, or something close to 70 nH, like 65 nH to 75 nH? Or does it mean that 70 nH is the highest value that the thing can do?
And does anyone have footprint for this inductor? Datasheet is so terrible, that I haven't even figured out whether this thing has 2 or 3 pins.
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

The datasheet says

> Inductance values from 9 to over 280 nH

That sentence is referring to the possible ranges of inductance values for all of the part numbers listed in the datasheet.

You must refer to the table on page 2 to find the actual inductance range for a specific part.  In your case you picked the 165-07A06SL, which is shown on the last line of the table.  This part can apparently be tuned between 70nH and 80nH depending on where you put the core (using the set screw).

> And does anyone have footprint for this inductor?

The hole pattern for the footprint is shown in the lower left corner of the first page of the datasheet.  It's up to you to decide how much annular ring to put on the holes.  The diagram shows two small holes for the leads, and two for the tabs on the shield (if you use the shielded version).  You can calculate the keepout for the footprint by using the package dimensions shown right next to the hole pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The data sheet shows this device has 2 pins and 2 tabs for the case. You seem to not have selected the best choice. P/N 165-06AOSC has a specified inductance range of 65-80 nH.